# Magnetic or True heading to determine approach frequency?

Tags: frequency

Say you are approaching a class C airport where it says (0 - 180) uses frequency A, and 181-359 uses B. If your true heading is 175 but your magnetic heading is 185, which frequency would you use?

Comment: The sectors for approach frequencies are bearings, not headings.

Comment: I get that it depends on your bearing, but the definition of bearing does not include magnetic or true, so my question still remains, frequency A or B?

Comment: In chapter 5 of the aim, it reads: "The straight-in area can be further divided into pie-shaped sectors with the boundaries identified by magnetic courses TO the . . ." leaving me to believe it is in reference to your magnetic bearing...

Answer (score 7):

Neither heading nor bearing, but rather *radial off the airport*, as the [Chart Supplement](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/) will tell you:
[image: Screenshot of the first paragraph of text in the "Communications" section of the "Airport/Facility Directory Legend" from an FAA Chart Supplement. The relevant text reads: "Frequencies will be listed, together with sectorization indicated by outbound radials, and hours of operation."]

Radar facility sectors are delineated by lines drawn on the radar scopes, and it is exceedingly unlikely for these lines to be perfectly aligned with radials off the airport. However, when you are within the "pie" formed by the specified radials, the given frequency is *likely* to be correct. If it is not, the controller will pass you on to the correct frequency; you should not worry too much about being overly precise.

As with everything in aviation, assume magnetic radial unless directed otherwise.

Comment: Isn't your bearing to the airport (or some specified Navaid) also determined by your physical location over the ground?  Aren't the radial from, and the bearing to, a given location, simply reciprocals?

Comment: @quietflyer I was thinking bearing from, not to.

Comment: Isn't "radial" a very VOR specific term?  (what's a radial off an airport?)  Bearing from/to is a general geographic term, and i think more correct.  (especially for a class C airport that might not be served by a VOR)

Comment: @MichaelHall and others: [from the *Airport/Facility Directory Legend*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ3Hs.png) in the [chart supplement](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/): "Frequencies will be listed, together with sectorization indicated by **outbound radials**, ..."

Comment: @randomhead - don't specifically disagree, but it would be helpful for clarity if the chart supplement for a particular C airspace airport would state "radials" from a navaid. The chart supplement for KTUS's C airspace, for example, suggests the bearing is from its ruways (rwys 11/29). Not related to the main point of this comment, but as you have pointed out TRACON sectors are not aligned to specific VOR radials. –